# How to suspend metro app on button click?

Tags: microsoft-metro

I just learnt that terminating the app in the code is not recommended, but how do I suspend an app in the click event of a button? I have a Close button in my app when clicked, should suspend the app. I don't want the user to hit ALT+f4 or anything. When the user clicks the app icon again from the Start icon, it should resume the app. How do I do it?

I'm looking for something like -

```
  private void btnSuspend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      //Suspend App.
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An app cannot suspend itself.  Windows manages the [lifetime of Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx) automatically.  An app will be suspended after a timeout of approximately ten seconds when it is no longer visible, or when the machine goes into a low power state.  When the user reactivates the app again (through Start, Alt-Tab, etc.) Windows will resume the app.

Comment: Interesting. I demoed my bare-bones app to the team and #1 question asked was - how do I get out of it? Why is `Application.Current.Exit();` not recommended? It seemed to do the job in my case. This is an intranet app by the way.

Comment: Learning to move between apps is fundamental to using Windows 8. Adding an escape hatch in your app doesn't help your users learn the common patterns present in every other app experience. There is a guideline doc that talks about not closing an app as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465088.aspx

Comment: Thanks Nathan! I'll check out that link.